# PHP redirect script does not work. Any idea why?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following code in my main index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/test.php"></script>
```

And the following is the code in test.php:

```
<?php
$referringDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$myDomain = 'mydomain.com';
if ( preg_match("($myDomain)i", $referringDomain, $matches) == false ) {
//no match - output redirect javascript
?>
window.top.location.href=’http://realdomain.com’;
<?
Die();
} else {
// do nothing
}
?>
```

However, the code doesn't seem to work in real-time. What could be wrong?

Comment: Your regex pattern is missing delimiters and you have used `’` instead of `'`.

Comment: You could alternatively redirect without relying on JavaScript altogether, using `header('Location: /some/other/url')` in your main PHP file

Comment: @PeeHaa, can you explain what you mean by my regex pattern is missing delimiters?

Comment: Gargon: This code is used to protect my website.

Comment: @TingPing Doing it inside PHP is more secure than doing it by JavaScript, as JS can be disabled - moreover, with JS, your entire page is served to the client, whereas in PHP you could immediately prevent any more data from being sent.

Comment: @TingPing http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Regex when you don't have to - you can `parse_url` the refferer and get the domain of it that way, then simply matching it against yours. Also, as PeeHaa pointed out, in the JavaScript, you used the wrong kind of quotes.

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referringURL = parse_url($referrer);
$myDomain = 'mydomain.com';

if ($referringURL['hostname'] !== $myDomain) {
  //no match - output redirect javascript
  echo "window.top.location.href='http://realdomain.com';";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$referringDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$myDomain = 'mydomain.com';
if ( preg_match("($myDomain)i", $referringDomain, $matches) == false ) {
//no match - output redirect javascript
?>
<script>
    window.top.location.href="http://realdomain.com";
</script>
<?php
Die();
} else {
// do nothing
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect a user to another page while your PHP code is executing:
You should use this BEFORE outputting (echoing) anything in browser:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.website.com/anotherpage.php") ;
  exit() ;
?>
```

**Current code execution will be terminated**, so you can decrease the load on your server. While using JavaScript, PHP will **execute code till the end**, output it into browser and only then browser will redirect a user.

But if you need redirection after the page is loaded, this is the option:

```
<script>
  window.location = "anotherpage.php" ;
  //or window.location.href = "anotherpage.php" ;
</script>
```

Edit: `header("Location: $url")` must contain absolute URL - Thanks to PeeHaa

Answer (score 0):

```
window.top.location.href=’http://realdomain.com’;
```

to

```
window.top.location.href='http://realdomain.com';
```

The quotes are wrong. Use single quotes.